# How to add pause/fast forward overlays in video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Suppose I have recorded some game footage. I'd like to turn this into an output video where at times I pause or fast-forward the source video. I'd like to add a sort of overlay where I show a play/pause/ffwd flashing icon in a corner.

Can anyone suggest any resources to investigate or ways to achieve this please?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: So you want a commentary video that plays at a normal steady FPS with the commented on video overlaid which can be paused, fast forwarded etc while being commented on and when that happens you want the over lay of a stylistic icon indicating the action? If you have the functionality working then you can just overlay an image from another source or create the icon in blender and overlay that Scene. Blender can support multiple Scenes

Comment: Yep that's basically it. I'll see if I can find an example as well. I'll have a play with using images and showing/hiding them as the flashing icon. Just wondered if there was anything out of the box really.